# How to use orbit stabilizer theorem to compute rotations of soccer ball

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, rotations, symmetry

**Question**: compute the order of the group of rotations of soccer ball ? and find it's group of rotations? Further, show that soccer ball can not have $60°$ rotational symmetry about line through the centre of two opposite hexagonal faces.

**My attempt**: In case of regular icosahedron (a solid with 20 congruent traingles as faces) I just denote each traingle face from 1 through 20 and then used the orbit stabilizer theorem. From which I get $|G|= |{\rm orb}_G(1)| |{\rm stab}_G(1)| =20• 3=60$

But here given that(soccer ball)  has  **20 faces that regular hexagon** and **12 faces that are regular pentagons**. So how $|G|$ computed?  **what to do of  that additional 12 pentagonal faces** ? How can i use the orbit stabilizer theorem? Please help.....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "can not have". What generalization of the soccer ball are you thinking of here? Clearly the soccer ball itself doesn't have this symmetry; and clearly there are solids that have this symmetry, so I presume "can not have" must refer to some intermediate class of solids with a common feature that precludes this symmetry?

Comment: @joriki sir I had typed the question as it is given in a book. "given a soccer ball has 20 faces that are regular hexagon and 12 faces that are regular pentagons. Use the orbit stabilizer theorem to explain why a soccer ball cannot have a $60°$ rotational symmetry about a line through the centres of two opposite hexagonal faces.